# Wave datasets from installed managed beta package not visible

Tags: deployment, beta-managed-package

I created a managed beta package with wave assets in one developer org, and successfully installed it into another developer org. I can see all the wave assets via the API (in Workbench), including the datasets. However, the datasets do not appear in Analytics Studio, and the lenses and dashboards will not open -- they show Resource Not Found errors.

Has anyone run into this before? I've noticed that the datasets installed from the managed package have different ids than they did in the packaging org. Do the dataset ids in the dashboard json files automatically get changed, or are they still set to the "old" dashboard ids?

Update: I found Salesforce Knowledge Article 000250116 at https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000250116&type=1 which stated that the datasets in a package are merely metadata; because the package is empty of data, it is invisible to the UI. I followed the steps, since my package had two datasets generated from Salesforce objects and two generated from .csv files. However, I got an error message that my .csv derived datasets could not be modified because they are parts of a package. Foiled again.